# UITextView getting blocked because peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic: getting called very fast

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager, cbperipheral, cbperipheralmanager

I am trying to show data in UITextView by appending data coming from `peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:error:`. In this case `peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:error:` is getting called very frequently, due to which `UITextView` (`self.responseTextView`) is either unable to print any data or blocks the UI.

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
{
    if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:UNKNOWN3_CHARACTERISTICS]]) 
   {
        NSData *data = characteristic.value;
        NSString *stringFromData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        self.responseTextView.text = [self.responseTextView.text stringByAppendingString:stringFromData];
        NSLog(@"%@",stringFromData);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the kind of value? Does the value changes? Is it numbers? If it's text, you may only update if the text change, if it's a number, you could wait for 5/10 values (depending) and do an average. You could count the times it's called, and update only if the count is enough high, or maybe use a timestamp and update only if a certain time passed. Or mix all theses ideas...

Comment: Are you certain that `didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:` is getting called on the main thread? UI updates won't work well from background threads.